# Set two javascript variables at once, ANGULAR

Tags: angular, angular-material

im trying to set two variables at once using a dialog popup but for some reason, it only shows the playerRequested variable but not the activity variable.
here it my html code

```
<body>
    <h1>Create A Team</h1>
    <p>Players Needed</p>
    <input matInput type="number" min="1" max="4" [(ngModel)]="data.requestedPlayers">

    <p>Activity</p>
    <mat-button-toggle-group #togglegroup = "matButtonToggleGroup" [(ngModel)]="data.activity">
        <mat-button-toggle value="Unrated">Unrated</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="Competitive">Competitive</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    {{togglegroup.value}}
    <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.activity" [mat-dialog-close]="data.requestedPlayers" cdkFocusInitial>Post</button>
</body>
```

and here is my .ts file

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogClose, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  requestedPlayers: string;
  activity: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'val-app';


  requestedPlayers : string;
  activity : string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateTeamOptions, {
      height: '326px',
      width: '237px',
      data: {requestedPlayers: this.requestedPlayers, activity: this.activity}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result =>{
      console.log('Dialog result is: '+ result.activity);
      this.requestedPlayers = result;
      this.activity = result;
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'create-team-options',
  templateUrl: 'create-team-options.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-team-options.scss']
})

export class CreateTeamOptions {


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateTeamOptions>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

on the open dialog it should save both variables from the html file where they were set but for some reason it doesnt.

if you lads could help that would be much appreciated!! 
thanks

Edited: just tried switching which one it sets first for the post button on html and it sets the first one to both but not sure how to set them differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `button` in your dialog component to return the entire `data` and it should work. Something like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Post</button>
```

With that done, your `result` object would have both the values.

Comment: Omg ur a God, thanks took me legit an hour and never thought of something simple like that. Thanks so much!

Comment: also i dont know how to close a question so if someone could tell me or do that it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog afterClose subscription, you should put `result.activity` in `this.activity` and `result.requestedPlayers`  in `this.requestedPlayers`  variables.